# Why is it returning false from the exception, when the try is working

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, google-bigquery

```
allAirports = []
allFlights = {}

def loadData(airportFile, flightFile):

    try:
        airFile = open(airportFile, "r")
        fileFlight = open(flightFile, "r")


        while True:

            line = airFile.readline()
            line = line.replace(' ', '')
            line = line.replace('  ', '')
            airList = list(line.split(','))
            airList[-1] = airList[-1].strip()

            if airList[0] == '':
                line1 = fileFlight.readline()
                line1 = line1.replace(' ', '')
                line1 = line1.replace('  ', '')
                line1 = line1.replace('    ', '')
                flightList = list(line1.split(','))
                flightList[-1] = flightList[-1].strip()

                for i in range (1):

                    line2 = getAirportByCode(flightList[1])
                    line2 = line2.replace('(', ' ')
                    line2 = line2.replace(')', ' ')
                    line2 = line2.replace(',', ' ')
                    line2 = line2.split()
                    line2[1] = re.sub(r"([A-Z])", r" \1", line2[1]).lstrip()
                    line2[2] = re.sub(r"([A-Z])", r" \1", line2[2]).lstrip()

                    line3 = getAirportByCode(flightList[2])
                    line3 = line3.replace('(', ' ')
                    line3 = line3.replace(')', ' ')
                    line3 = line3.replace(',', ' ')
                    line3 = line3.split()
                    line3[1] = re.sub(r"([A-Z])", r" \1", line3[1]).lstrip()
                    line3[2] = re.sub(r"([A-Z])", r" \1", line3[2]).lstrip()

                    if flightList[1] in allFlights:
                        allFlights[flightList[1]] += [Flight(flightList[0], Airport(line2[0], line2[1], line2[2]), Airport(line3[0], line3[1], line3[2]))]
                    else:
                        allFlights.setdefault(flightList[1], [])
                        allFlights[flightList[1]] += [Flight(flightList[0], Airport(line2[0], line2[1], line2[2]), Airport(line3[0], line3[1], line3[2]))]
            else:
                allAirports.append(Airport(airList[0], airList[1], airList[2]))
    except:

        return False

def getAirportByCode(code):
    code1 = code
    for i in range (len(allAirports)):
        if code1 in str(allAirports[i]):
            return (str(allAirports[i]).replace(' ', ''))
    return -1

t1 = loadData("airports.txt", "flights.txt")
total = 0
for i in allFlights:
    total += len(allFlights[i])
print(t1)
if t1 and len(allAirports) == 37 and total == 146:
    print("Test 4 Passed. (loadData())")
else:
    print("Test 4 Failed. (loadData())")
```

When I run the code it return False with the exception, even when the try is working? can anyone tell me why this isn't working? or if I am missing something. Idk it the while statement is the problem but idk what to change it to. Please let me know why false it printing on my screen. Program is for a school project

Comment: You suppress all information about the exception with that exception handler. Why have it at all as the errors would be a good thing to know about. As a minimum, print the error and traceback. At lease `import traceback` and then `traceback.print_exc()`

Comment: Your while loop never ends so eventually there is no more data to read. Something like `airList[-1] = airList[-1].strip()` will fail.

Comment: i must say, that is a large try block.  better to split into smaller blocks to identify potential different errors...

Answer (score 0):

How can you tell? I assume the function returna `None`, because it has no other return statement. And in the if statement below, `t1` being `None` will be interpreted the same way as `False`.

To summarize: you need to return true if your method succeeds.